# CakePHP redirect to blank page

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I have a problem with the redirection with cakephp 2.x.

When I execute the function below the redirect it works perfectly:

```
public function test() {
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'));
}
```

But when I execute a trasaction with the database (add, modify and delete), the function redirect me to a blank page:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Post->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    if ($this->Post->deleteAll(array('Post.id' => $id), false)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__(" success."), 'flash', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__("error."), 'flash', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'));
}
```

Redirection does not work.
Thank you for helping me

Comment: have you tried to redirect to different controller?

Comment: What do you mean with "blank page"? Is the URL in your browser `/pages/index` or something different? Have you checked the error log files in your CakePHP folders? Have you checked the HTTP response code with webdeveloper tool in your browser (what error code, e.g. 404/500)? Might the blank page be caused by the destination of the redirect (index action in your pages controller)?...

Answer (score 0):

Have you check with the debug 1 or 2 , if it shows some type of error.Moreover why are you using deleteAll for deleting single record, use delete method instead of deleteAll.

```
$this->Post->delete($id);
```

Comment: Yes I tested with debug 1 and 2 but still the same result : a blank page

Comment: I also try to delete ($id) but still it does not work

Comment: Is the record is deleted from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if there is anything printed before redirect acting, even if it is a space which can prevent redirect.

Comment: you also can remove ending php tags (?>) from classes to ensure spaces in pages

Comment: i checked if e white space exist but still it doesn't work